# Is there a way to reset sound settings : Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, suspend

I was having problems with sounds when resuming from sleep and I tried various solutions online but nothing has worked and actually things have gotten worst. I'm experiencing the following problems with sound:

- Sound settings have disappeared from the system settings dialog and so has the sound status from the menu bar, I can still adjust the volume using the Fn key
- Whenever the computer wakes up from suspend mode the sound plays through both the analog jack and the internal speakers
- The sound cuts off periodically and I get the following error on VLC:

  > Audio output failed:
  >   The audio device "sysdefault:CARD=PCH" could not be used:
  >   Device or resource busy.

So is there a way to revert to the original ubuntu sound settings without reinstalling the OS altogether?

**UPDATE**

- Status icon fixed with: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-sound-gtk2` but sound settings still missing

Comment: ...if you have a list of all the thing you did, and you post it, maybe someone can help. Without that, a crystal ball could be the only solution....  Unless you changed only things in your home directory, in which case creating a new user should suffice.

Comment: I can suggest the following - try running `gnome-settings-daemon` from the command line, play around with `alsamixer` . Try reinstalling `indicator-sound-gtk2` with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-sound-gtk2` and if that doesn't work try `volti`, which is a volume icon similar to default volume indicator, or `gnome-alsamixer`, which is a graphical front-end to `alsamixer` ; I use both in my minimalistic GUI with openbox. Your sound appears to work, but not the graphical interface to it, so issue isn't bad - there has to be a simple solution.

Comment: @Rmano I wish I could tell you but I can't remember, some of it involved playing around with pulseaudio/alsa and some configuration files...

Comment: @Serg Okay the status icon is back but the settings are still missing from the system settings dialog. Running `gnome-settings-daemon` outputs the following error: **`You can only run one xsettings manager at a time; exiting`**

Answer (score 3):

<sup>All references to *Applications* in this answer refer to the applications menu item in the control panel.</sup>

---

### Xfce - Audio Mixer

*(See note below)*

As [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) uses [Xfce](http://xfce.org/) desktop environment you could install [*Audio Mixer*](http://www.xfce.org/about/tour46), `xfce4-mixer`, if it has been removed (optionally with `--reinstall`).

```
$ sudo apt-get install xfce4-mixer
```

and use the *Audio Mixer* found under

- *Applications -> Multimedia -> Audio Mixer*

or:

```
$ xfce4-mixer
```

then tweak around.

### Control panel

To add it to your control panel go to settings manager:

- *Applications -> Settings -> Settings Manager*

  - Select *Panels*

or:

- *Applications -> Settings -> Panels*

or:

```
$ xfce4-panel -p
```

Then select the *Items* tab and add (the [+] button) where you select *Audio Mixer*.

This is a very minimal audio controller. (Volume up/down - what else does one need?). To configure simply right-click the control-icon and select *Properties*, or select *Run Audio Mixer* if need be.

#### PA - pavucontrol

If you run [Pulse Audio](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio)) you could also use the [*PulseAudio Volume Control*](http://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/pavucontrol/#overview). Should be under *Multimedia* if installed, or start it from command line by:

```
$ pavucontrol
```

If not installed the package has the same name.

```
$ sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

This is the one I mainly use to adjust sound settings by GUI. (When not using JACK)

### Note: Audio Mixer

As per [Xfce 4.12 release notes](http://www.xfce.org/about/news/?post=1425081600):

> *“Due to gstreamer1.0 having dropped the mixer-interface entirely, and xfce4-mixer and xfce4-volumed relying on this interface with gstreamer0.10, our mixer application and volume daemon cannot be ported to 1.0 and are consequently not maintained anymore.”*

As such I guess it would be best to rely on other controls such as *pavucontrol* in the future unless Xfce comes along with a new one.

But, it *should* work, and works fine here. I have both gstreamer 0.10  and 1.

Only to note that it *could* disappear in future releases.

---

#### Sub note:

After last update the audio settings was all re-configured as well as several others - such as keyboard tuning (I have for example a much lower repeat delaaaaaaaaaaaaaaay then default etc.)

Audio card was switched to HDMI (on monitor) instead of internal. Disabled audio such as input microphone was switched on etc.

Passed by here as I wondered if anyone else had similar issues.

Comment: Thanks for your help... I don't seem to be having anymore issues with sound after a normal boot up. But things are still sketchy after resuming from suspend...sometimes it's fine, sometimes I have to restart to get the sound working again

Comment: @LucinoVeo: What is your setup? Do you run a "clean" Xubuntu? I have a modified hack. Do you use PulseAudio? Do you have `pavucontrol` (as mentioned in post) installed?

Comment: it seems like things kind of mysteriously sorted themselves out... I hope your post can be of use to someone else anyway! Thanks

Comment: Still missing in 16.04 and the Audio Controll / Volume will not be set in Settings or the pannels, old one still in indicator plugin - but only working partially!